# fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type is not found in assemblies

Tags: c#-3.0, selenium-rc, fitnesse

Purpose: [Automation]Open email.com site and login [by SeleniumRC in C#.NET]

I want to Test using Fitnesse framework on Selenium RC

Question: I am not sure of how to write an Action Fixture, Please guide me.

Following is Fitnesse code using Action Fixture for the Selenium RC code.

```
!define COMMAND {.\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {.\Runner.exe}
!define path {.\emailTesting12.dll}

!|ActionFixture|
|start|emailTesting12.emailTest|
|enter|SetupTest|localhost|4444|*chrome|w3.email.com|xxx@email|pwd|
```

ERROR : on executing the above code in Fitnesse- error occured is:

1. fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type'emailTesting12.emailTest'notfound in                 assemblies:
2. fitSharp.Machine.Exception.MemberMissingException: Member 'setuptest' with 1 parameter(s) not found    for type 'System.Object'.
3. fitSharp.Machine.Exception.MemberMissingException: Member 'thetestemailtest' with 1         parameter(s) not   found for type 'System.Object'.

Following is the Selenium RC code in  C#.Net

```
namespace emailTesting12
{

    Class emailTest : fit.Fixture
    { 
        private ISelenium selenium; 
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

        public void SetupTest()  
        {  
            selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 9999, "*chrome", "https://email.com/");`     
            selenium.Start(); 
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();` 
        }

        public void TeardownTest()  
        {
            try   
            {
                selenium.Stop();      
            }
            catch (Exception) 
            {
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        public void TheTestemailTest() 
        {
            selenium.Open("http://mail.email.com"); 
            selenium.Type("id=Email", "uname");  
            selenium.Type("id=Passwd", "xxxx"); 
            selenium.Click("id=signIn"); // login
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("300000");            
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            emailTest g = new emailTest();
            g.SetupTest();
            g.TheTestemailTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve the same.

Comment: Hi @rdp it's not entirely clear what you're asking here. Would you be able to clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: Edited the Question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Define the path with `!path`, not `!define path` e.g. `!path c:\mypath\myCode.dll`

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/UsingFitnesse.html

Comment: Define is required in !path for Fitnesse to communicate with the Fixture code. I tried not working